# Share File using Nativescript Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I can't find anywhere in the documentation about sharing files. Does Nativescript have a built in way to share filesystem files? I.E. I can pass it a path and it'll open the menu to pick an app to share with and when that app is opened it has that file specified already attached?

I'm using a plugin already for this, but it's a bit finicky as in it attaches the file to an email, but fails to attach it to a text message. Also the plugin doesn't give a complete list of applications like the built in share does on the phone.

Comment: which plugin are you using for that? I don't think there is in bukt library to support the same.

Comment: I'm using the Share File plugin like the one listed below.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm [Share File](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-share-file) plugin works as I'm personally using it often.

If you face any issues, let's know when it fails / which app you are exactly trying to share the file with.

Comment: this is not the answer, mate :)

Comment: Rephrased, the more detail a question is and the better the answers are ;) Anyways thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So, I'm using this plugin actually sorry forgot to add that. I'm trying to add a .vcf file to a text message. Works with an email. Not all text message apps on the device show up under the app selection. Even though they all support it. The text message app that only shows up is Textra. Which when the plugin tries to attach to the text message, it improperly does. It just shows up as a black square. Try to send the message to see if it's just a weird ui bug it doesn't send anything. Like I said email on the other hand like Gmail. It attaches the file fine and sends it properly.

Comment: Of course you may aware that SMS can't have attachments, only MMS can. The plugin does nothing fancy here but just throws an intent with specific types set. It should be the third party app responsible for parsing the file correctly form the given intent. I'm using Android 8.x on Moto G5 Plus, the default message app attaches the file to a new MMS as expected. To verify it's not a plugin issue, you may use any file manager app (ES File Explorer for instance), try to open the file and use the share option given there and see if you still see same issues with Textra, if then it's with their app.

Comment: If the file manager app works with Textra, may be there is a chance it could be something with plugin. I would recommend you to create a Playground and share here so it will be easy to debug further.

Comment: I'm on a Samsung S9. The built in file explorer share option on the file works fine with the .vcf file. The only difference I can see is that when Textra opens from this share option it auto converts the message to an MMS unlike the plugin. Also the file explorer share options gives me a list of all the text message apps on my phone unlike the plugin as well. I.E. the default messenger app from samsung is listed and not with the plugin.
I'll try and get a playground working.

Comment: Android applications rely on intents to communicate, it may not be possible to declare one intent that satisfies all different apps. Thats being said, I'm unsure why the plugin author have used certain methods, he might had his reasons and test cases he followed. So here is an updated example (https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=hDFbJ1&v=2), I would like you to try and see if this helps your scenario.

Comment: The same functionality happens with the text message. Still not getting the list of apps I'm expecting. I'm not sure what would trigger that list either.

Comment: It works on my end, I even tried by installing Textra it was listed so the default message app.

Comment: Manoj I have screenshots I can share with you from my device showing you what I see. If you would like to see. At least for the S9 it does not work.

Comment: @Shortcircuit, did you find a solution for this? I am trying something similar--send a file by text message to another user, and that user taps the file to have my app open the file and parse it. Not sure if share file (or anything else) can do that:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775807/open-file-from-text-message-with-nativescript