# Open File From Text Message with Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

In my nativescript iOS app, users will create a file, and then share the file via text message with other users. I'm using angular.

I expect that I can use the file system to create and save the file, and then use nativescript-share-file to open up the text message and attach the file.

BUT: how do I enable the recipient to tap on the file in the text message, and have that tap automatically **open the app with the file there?**

It's that piece I am not sure of: user taps on the file in the text message and this tap 1) opens the app, and 2) the app reads the file.

This is functionality a variety of apps have. For example, if you send someone a youtube video via text, they can tap on the message and have the video open in youtube. Same with sending people podcasts via iOS's podcast app.

How can I enable this in my nativescript iOS app?

EDIT 1: Note that, while sms messages have strict limits, iphone does allow you to attach files by using iMessage or (if iMessage is not available) MMS. So attaching and sending the file should not be a problem.

EDIT 2: **the key is: how can I have my app open a file a user receives via text?** The best way may be to include my app in iOS's "open in..." option, discussed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html). But how do I do that in Nativescript?

Comment: When you share file via nativescript-share-file, it actually sends a copy of the file to destination app so the app should be able to open the file when user clicks it. If it's not happening, please provide more details like what file format you are using and which app you are intended to share the with.

Comment: I had not picked on that. I can use share file to 1) open text message with file, 2) send the text message to another user, specifying the destination app in the file, and 3) recipient taps on file, phone reads destination app, opens app, and app reads the file?

Comment: To be clear: 1) the app is the app I'm developing and 2) there is no separate server to coordinate the app across different devices--the file would have to be shared via a pre-existing method of transfer such as text message or email.

Comment: @Manoj, I am still not sure that plugin allows me to do what I am trying to do--sending a file via text message that the recipient device will know requires opening by my app on their phone. Where is information about setting the destination app? I am not finding any docs that describe that, or any sample code for the plugin other than the very minimal amount in the readme.